# Como hacer la busqueda por numero de telefono en odoo v14 en el modulo de ventas

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
<field name="partner_id" widget="res_partner_many2one" context="{'res_partner_search_mode': 'customer', 'show_address': 1, 'show_vat': True}" options='{"always_reload": True}'/>
```

Este campo es el cliente y por defecto ya se puede buscar por el nombre o el número de identificación, ahora lo que quiero hacer es poder buscarlo tambien por el número de telefono, use este codigo pero no me funciona.

```
<record id="view_sale_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit.searchphone</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="partner_id" widget="res_partner_many2one"
                   context="{'res_partner_search_mode': 'customer', 'show_address': 1, 'show_vat': True}"
                   options='{"always_reload": True}'
                   filter_domain="['|', '|', ('name', 'ilike', self), ('vat', 'ilike', self), ('phone', 'ilike', self), ('mobile', 'ilike', self)]"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.